# Retrieve document only my condition meet all element in sub array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How to retrieve document only my condition meet all element in subarray?

my documents:

```json
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5234cc89687ea597eabee675"),
        "code" : "xyz",
        "tags" : [ 
            "school", 
            "book", 
            "bag", 
            "headphone", 
            "appliance"
        ],
        "qty" : [ 
            {
                "size" : "S",
                "num" : 10,
                "color" : "blue"
            }, 
            {
                "size" : "M",
                "num" : 45,
                "color" : "blue"
            }, 
            {
                "size" : "M",
                "num" : 60,
                "color" : "blue"
            }, 
            {
                "size" : "L",
                "num" : 100,
                "color" : "green"
            }
        ]
    }
    
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5234cc8a687ea597eabee676"),
        "code" : "abc",
        "tags" : [ 
            "appliance", 
            "school", 
            "book"
        ],
        "qty" : [ 
            {
                "size" : "6",
                "num" : 100,
                "color" : "green"
            }, 
            {
                "size" : "6",
                "num" : 50,
                "color" : "blue"
            }, 
            {
                "size" : "8",
                "num" : 100,
                "color" : "brown"
            }
        ]
    }
```

for this query I retreive this document but I expected no result, because in the array there is an element with the value 60...
all elements of the array must meet the condition

```js
    db.getCollection('test').find({
                         qty: { $all: [
                                        { "$elemMatch" : { size: "M", num: { $lt: 50} } }
                                      ] }
                       } )
```

my result is:

```json
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5234cc89687ea597eabee675"),
        "code" : "xyz",
        "tags" : [ 
            "school", 
            "book", 
            "bag", 
            "headphone", 
            "appliance"
        ],
        "qty" : [ 
            {
                "size" : "S",
                "num" : 10,
                "color" : "blue"
            }, 
            {
                "size" : "M",
                "num" : 45,
                "color" : "blue"
            }, 
            {
                "size" : "M",
                "num" : 60,
                "color" : "blue"
            }, 
            {
                "size" : "L",
                "num" : 100,
                "color" : "green"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Or in this situation only result a items that meet the condition, but not all :

```js
    db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
        { $unwind: '$qty'},
        { $match: {'qty.size': {$eq: "M"}}},
        { $match: {'qty.num': {$lt: 50}}}
    ])
```

my result is:

```json
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5234cc89687ea597eabee675"),
        "code" : "xyz",
        "tags" : [ 
            "school", 
            "book", 
            "bag", 
            "headphone", 
            "appliance"
        ],
        "qty" : {
            "size" : "M",
            "num" : 45,
            "color" : "blue"
        }
    }
```

Comment: So you want to make sure there is no item with the matching "size" but in the "wrong" size in the array?, other sizes don't matter when it comes to this validation?

Comment: this element with size m and num 60, don't rispect all items in array, I need to return documents parents with only sub array are all items in condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$map` to create an auxiliary array of booleans to perform the checking on your criteria. Afterwards, use `$allElementsTrue` to perform the filtering.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "filterArr": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$qty",
          "as": "q",
          "in": {
            $and: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$$q.size",
                  "M"
                ]
              },
              {
                $lt: [
                  "$$q.num",
                  50
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        "$allElementsTrue": "$filterArr"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      filterArr: false
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LSc-bttzYFc) for your reference.